# url is incorrect when return View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Inside my controller i'm returning a View which works fine except that the Url is not what I expected because it's replacing with the name of the action method it's in.

```
http://hostname/Controller/SubmitTicket

instead of

http://hostname/Controller/Detail
```

And I can't do a redirect to action in this case.

```
    public ActionResult Detail()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult SubmitTicket()
    {
        return View("Detail");
    }
```

```
<h2>Detail</h2>

<% using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitTicket", "Home"))
   { %>
       <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
   <% } %>
```

Comment: How are you generating the url?

Comment: @Fourth - How do i post my routes?

Comment: @ZippyV - return View("Detail", checkModel);

Comment: @rod - That code doesn't generate the url.

Comment: URL's are in the form of http://foo/controllerName/actionMethodName and not http://foo/controllerName/viewName

Comment: @rod The ASP.NET MVC route collection is defined in the `Global.asax.cs` file inside the `RegisterRoutes()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MVC the URL used will always be based on the Action.

I think what is happening is you are doing a POST to http://hostname/Controller/SubmitTicket, and then returning the Detail view. In this case the URL will be the URL you submitted to.

Hence if you want a different URL, one option is you need to change the name of your SubmitTicket action or define a different route for it. But I don't think that will solve your problem.

If you are doing a post, and want to show the user a detail page after the post, use the [Post/Redirect/Get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

```
public ActionResult Detail()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult SubmitTicket()
{
    return RedirectToAction("Detail")
}
```